# Metal texture / CGImage from data asset

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoa, cocoa-touch, metal

I believe native reading of OpenEXR format is (unofficially) supported both on recent macOS and iOS versions: [Is OpenEXR supported on iOS / macOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48832869/518169)

I'd like to load an OpenEXR image to a Metal texture, probably via `MTKTextureLoader.newTexture()`.

My problem is that XCode doesn't recognise OpenEXR files as texture assets, but as data asset.

This means I cannot use `MTKTextureLoader.newTexture(name: textureName, ...)`.

What cross platform (recent macOS / iOS) options are there to read an image from a data asset?

Since `.newTexture` supports CGImage, I'd guess that the natural way would be to load into CGImage, but I don't quite understand how.

Or should I simply make an URL out of the data asset's file and try to load that one?